# PreparedStatement: Java8 OffsetDateTime to Postgresql Timestamp with time zone

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, java-8

Is a direct mapping from Java 8' OffsetDateTime type to PostgreSQL's Timestamp with time zone in a Java PreparedStatement possible?

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html says it has to be done using `setObject`, however it didn't work for me.

My Prepared statement is a PostgreSQL function call. The function's argument is a timestamp with time zone.
I tried it with `prepareCall` and `prepareStatement`. Both don't work.

My pom.xml has the newest postgresql driver:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and I also tried this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</version>
</dependency>

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = FileUtil.getCreationDateTime(absolutePath)
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select import_file(?) ;");
stmt.setObject(1, offsetDateTime);
stmt.executeUpdate(); --> error "column "x" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text". Hint:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The parameter list of the function expects a column "x" with type timestamp with time zone.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.import_file(    
    x timestamp with time zone)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    INSERT INTO datei VALUES (nextval('datei_pk_datei_id_seq'::regclass), x);       
    RETURN currval('datei_pk_datei_id_seq'::regclass);
END;$BODY$
```

Comment: show some minimal code that you can test against., or at least some code and error that you get

Comment: ` PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("select `callMyfunction(?) ;");
   stmt.setObject(1, offsetDateTime);
stmt.executeUpdate()`

The error is column <x> is of type  timestamp with time zone, but the expression is a text

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Please [edit] the question and add the extra information in the question itself. Use the comments for short replies or to notify people that you have made edits in the question. Also make sure you show us how you create the `offsetDateTime` object.

Comment: OK, the fact that it says something about column "x" makes me think that the problem is in the stored procedure itself. Can you add its source?

Comment: Are sure you really execute the query above? `column "x"` is very suspicious (there is no column involved in a function call). -- Please try with `stmt.setObject(1, offsetDateTime, java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE);`

Comment: I tried that already. it doesn't help. Column "x" is the name of my column in the table.

Comment: @aap then most probably your error comes from the function body. Please show us the definition of the function too (and the complete error message, with DETAIL, CONTEXT, and HINTs)

Comment: Please post the **whole definition** (i.e. `CREATE FUNCTION` statement). The parameter list is as important as the body, in your situation.

Comment: my parameter list expects a column <x> with type timestamp with time zone

Comment: If you really want to get an answer to your question, please put in the effort to provide all the necessary details. This means that if people ask you for the full CREATE FUNCTION statement, you put in the full statement, not just the body, and not just a comment about what the function expects.

Comment: I wonder, if my problem is a well known bug, or unimplemented feature of PostgreSQL

Comment: anyone any suggestions?

Comment: I solved that issue. It was not related to the problem described above. Thank you all.